# What is "Holly Hack" in CSS design

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer

i know it is something related to old versions of IE bugs, but other than that, there are no specific definition of what kinda of hack is that.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=holly+hack

Comment: Adding `css` to that Google URL would have been much more useful

Comment: What's especially amusing @buonzz is that your most recent blog post is titled: **Other cool stuffs [sic] you can do within the Google Search** - http://buonzz.appspot.com/single.jsp?key=2002 - did you forget that you can also search for stuff with it??

Comment: yeah bud, i already read the stuff, but aside from the height:1% stuff, i want more clear stuff

Comment: notice that the google search for 'holly hack' now returns this page as the second result...

Answer (score 5):

Named after Holly Bergevin, [this article](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=C37E0) is the definitive source for the details of the hack(s). Generally, the hack(s) are workaround for IE6 CSS deficiencies / rendering bugs.

Comment: +1 heh. I thought it was called 'holly' because `\*/` looks like a sprig of holly leaves and berries.

Comment: yeah, thats what im trying to figure out, what the the word "Holly" is all about, and why it relates to ie hack

Comment: @andyb that link is dead. archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150324181023/http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=C37E0